# Why is my tomcat not reusing threads?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

I am trying to understand how tomcat uses threads to serve requests. I have the following situation with a web application when doing load tests:

A test client sends "login" requests to the server. Each login request contains different user credentials (i.e. the web application creates a new session for each request). The requests are sent in a very "nice" manner: the test client sends a login request, waits a specific amount of time, sends the next login request, etc.

From my understanding of tomcat, I would have expected that a few threads are enough to serve the incoming requests since the requests are arriving perfectly sequentially. However, the following is happening: I can see in the JVM that the number of threads is going up and up (above 100) until I get the famous "OutOfMemory exception: cannot create native thread". Increasing the "maxThreads" configuration parameter delays but not avoids the exception.

I am not a tomcat expert, so my two questions are:

1. Is it normal that tomcat needs so many threads for many sessions? I thought the number of needed threads depends on the number of concurrent requests, and not on the number of sessions. As I wrote, I have no concurrent requests. The test client gets a response before sending the next request.
2. If it is *not* normal, what could be the reason for this behavior? Could it be that something is preventing tomcat to re-use an idle thread? In what directions do I have to search? Open files, database connections,...?

Thanks for your comments

Edit: netstat does not show anything strange. No connections staying open longer than they should.

Edit 2: Probably important: I am using tomcat 7 (customer needs for reasons unknown to me). As far as I can see in the thread list it's using BIO, which shouldn't really make a difference here.

Comment: @Fildor Hmm, very good question. The test client is a Javascript program (in Chrome) using jQuery.ajax() to send synchronous requests to the server. In the network view of the developer console, it looks like things are terminating normally, but I don't know how trustable that view if it really comes down to the behavior of the TCP connection.
(Strange, Fildor's comment is gone? He asked whether my test client closes connections properly)

Comment: Take a thread dump and see what those threads are doing.

Comment: @MarkThomas I have looked at the thread dump. The threads aren't doing anything. They are waiting in the thread pool to get a job from the job queue.

Comment: By the way, I have added a second edit to my original posting, explaining that I am using tomcat 7.